# Are there any odd primes like this?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Are there any odd primes $p, q, r$ such that

$$(p-1)(q-1)(r-1)\mid pqr-1$$

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem? Can you see any way to solve sub-problems like, for instance, whether there are solutions to $2(p-1)(q-1)(r-1)=pqr-1$?

Comment: I do like the problem, but as Milo mentions it will likely be put on hold unless your efforts to solve it are included in the problem.

Answer (score 3):

No, there are not.  Roughly speaking, because you can't have $(p-1)(q-1)(r-1)=pqr-1$, you need a factor of at least two between the sides, but the $pqr$ on each side is too big compared to the things you subtract.

To sketch a more rigorous argument, we can demand $p \le q \le r$  If $p=3$, we are asking that $2(q-1)(r-1)|3qr-1$ or $2qr-2q-2r+2|3qr-1$  It is clear the two sides cannot be equal, so we need the right at least double the left.  To be double, we would need $q+r \gt \frac {qr}2$, which cannot happen as $q,r$ are too large.  The same happens even more if $p \gt 3$

Answer (score -2):

Pseudoprimes do just this.  They pass Fermat's little theorm for all non-divisors. but are composite.  They are rarer then primes, but there are some classical ones.  One happens before 1000, and three come to mind less than 2000.

Comment: If there are three that small, maybe you could list them?

Comment: (Also, are all pseudoprimes the product of three primes? And isn't the condition for pseudoprime-ness just that $lcm(p-1,q-1,r-1)\mid pqr -1$?)

Comment: Are you referring to [Carmichael numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number) like $1105 = 5 \cdot 13 \cdot 17$? I know that $4, 12,$ and $16$ all divide $1105 - 1$, but their product doesn't. Am I missing something?

Comment: If you multiply p-1 and q-1 and r-1, you get pqr-1 - (pq+pr+qr) + (p+q+r)  For example, 6*12*18 = 1296.  

I suspect that finding a solution to p(q+r-1) + q(r-1)+r that p divides is a bit of a hassle, especially when applied to all three.

Comment: Moreover, I fail to see any use in it.  

I would have spent the time looking for second degree pseudoprimes, where p+1, q+1, r+1, also divide pqr+1, (which passes another kind of prime test, but is not prime), but i imagine such don't exist.